KOMA: Custom Suffix for Subparagraph Numbering (Sectioning)

I have an existing complicated LaTeX document, based on the documentclass scrbook.
I use the heading level subparagraph for a special purpose in this document.
Main Goal: I now want an functional addition to the subparagraph command: I want to add an optional argument, that adds a custom suffix after the number.
The suffix will be short, in the form of A1B5C2 or _A1-B5-C2 or  (A1-B5-C2).
If relevant, the suffix does not need to (but can be) be considered/displayed in the TOC or any other LaTeX functionality.
Remark: I am afraid of breaking things (unintedned side effects).

MWE
\documentclass{scrbook}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
    
% Add skip after (sub)paragraph level
\RedeclareSectionCommands[afterskip = 1sp]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\title{MWE for Suffix for Section Numbering}
\author{Manuel}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\subparagraph{subparagraph}

Text.

\end{document}


Dream Outcome / Interface
\subparagraph[P1-B4-F4]{Test} will lead to a heading like this: Test (P1-B4-F4). It is also ok, if the command name subparagraph changes.

I am "away from keyboard" over the weekend most of the time but I will reply after the weekend.

The syntax of the sectioning commands and the semantic of the arguments defined by \DeclareSectionCommand etc. is specified by that command and explained in the KOMA-Script documentation. You cannot simply change it. I also would not change the semantic of the optional argument, because this would break the possibility to use, e.g., a different ToC entry.
Instead you can define a new command to add an additional optional argument at the end:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subparagraphnumdepth}% number \subparagraph
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subparagraphtocdepth}% show \subparagraph in ToC


% Add suffix to the numbering of the subparagraph level
\renewcommand*\subparagraphformat[1]{\thesubparagraph\numbersuffix\autodot\enskip}
\newcommand*\numbersuffix{}

% Add skip after (sub)paragraph level
\RedeclareSectionCommands[afterskip = 1sp]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\NewDocumentCommand{\specialparagraph}{O{#2}mo}{%
  \IfValueT{#3}{\def\numbersuffix{#3}}% comment this line, to ignore the suffixes
  \subparagraph[#1]{#2}%
  \let\numbersuffix\relax
}

\title{MWE for Suffix for Section Numbering}
\author{Manuel}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\specialparagraph{subparagraph}

Text.

\specialparagraph[toc entry for second subparagraph]{second subparagraph}[A1B5C2]

Text.

\specialparagraph{third subparagraph}[\_A1-B5-C2]

Text.

\specialparagraph{fourth subparagraph}[ (A1-B5-C2)]

Text.

\specialparagraph{fifth subparagraph}

Text.

\end{document}

or you can copy the original definition to a new command and then redefine the original using the new command:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subparagraphnumdepth}% number \subparagraph
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subparagraphtocdepth}% show \subparagraph in ToC

% Add suffix to the numbering of the subparagraph level
\renewcommand*\subparagraphformat[1]{\thesubparagraph\numbersuffix\autodot\enskip}
\newcommand*\numbersuffix{}

% Add skip after (sub)paragraph level
\RedeclareSectionCommands[afterskip = 1sp]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalsubparagraph}{\subparagraph}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subparagraph}{sO{#3}mo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\originalsubparagraph*{#3}}{% star form
    \IfValueT{#4}{\def\numbersuffix{#4}}% comment this line, to ignore the suffixes
    \originalsubparagraph[#2]{#3}%
    \let\numbersuffix\relax
  }%
}

\title{MWE for Suffix for Section Numbering}
\author{Manuel}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\subparagraph{subparagraph}

Text.

\subparagraph[toc entry for second subparagraph]{second subparagraph}[A1B5C2]

Text.

\subparagraph{third subparagraph}[\_A1-B5-C2]

Text.

\subparagraph{fourth subparagraph}[ (A1-B5-C2)]

Text.

\subparagraph{fifth subparagraph}

Text.

\end{document}

Both solutions do not show the number suffix in the ToC:

but in the headings:

And because the number is only added via \subparagraphformat is also not shown in references using \label and \ref.
Note: I've increased tocdepth to show, that subparagraph entries in the ToC would not show the number suffix.
To ignore all the optional suffix arguments, you either have to comment the line that defines \numbersuffix in \specialsubparagraph resp. \subparagraph, or just remove/comment the redefinition of \subparagraphformat.

+1: Looks great! I wait a bit before accepting but it looks really good.

Please allow me a follow up question, but I can also ask a new septate question if you want that: Is it possible to have a variable (flag) to switch the new functionality on and off? Meaning, that there is a flag that causes the additional argument to be ignored. That way, I can compile the same document with and without the suffix.

IMHO the redefinition version should also handle the star form \subparagraph*.

@Schweinebacke You are right.

@Dr.ManuelKuehner I've optimized the code and added some notes about how to ignore the optional suffix argument. (And I've deleted the previous comment about it, because the improved code also handles \subparagraph* and therefore the argument declaration and numbers changed.)

Thanks a lot to you and @schweinebacke

Is it still possible to compile the document with no suffixes if needed for a special document version? Let me know if I am unclear.

@Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes. See the comments in the code and the last paragraph of the answer.
